# can't execute Junit test on J2EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, null, ejb

i have been trying to execute a junit test on my J2EE application for a week but i couldn't .here is my code and console error that show where i execute the test:

The test Code:

```
private List<Eleve> listEleves;
private Eleve eleve;
 private GestionEntitiesBean gestionEntitiesBean;


@BeforeClass
public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
    // one-time initialization code   
    System.out.println("@BeforeClass - oneTimeSetUp");
}

@AfterClass
public static void oneTimeTearDown() {
    // one-time cleanup code
    System.out.println("@AfterClass - oneTimeTearDown");
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    listEleves = new ArrayList<Eleve>();
    gestionEntitiesBean=Utils.getGestionEntitiesBean();
    System.out.println("@Before - setUp");
     eleve=new Eleve();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    listEleves.clear();
    System.out.println("@After - tearDown");
}




@Test
public final void testNewEleve() {
    fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO
}

@Test
public final void testMajEleve() {
    fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO
}

@Test
public final void testDelEleve() {
    fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO
}

@Test
public final void testGetAllEleve() {
//  fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO

    listEleves =gestionEntitiesBean.getAllEleve();
    assertEquals(1, listEleves.size());

}

@Test
public final void testGetEleveFromId() {
    fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO
}
```

}

The repository or the EJB code:

```
public class EleveRepository {

private EntityManager em;

public EleveRepository(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

public void newEleve(Eleve eleve) {
    em.persist(eleve);
    em.flush();
}

public void majEleve(Eleve eleve) {
    em.merge(eleve);
    em.flush();
}

public void delEleve(Eleve eleve) {
    em.remove(em.merge(eleve));
    em.flush();
}

public List<Eleve> getAllEleve() {
    TypedQuery<Eleve> q = em.createQuery("Select e FROM Eleve e",Eleve.class);
    List<Eleve> listEleve = q.getResultList();

    return listEleve;
}

public Eleve getEleveFromId(Integer id) {
    TypedQuery<Eleve> q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Eleve e where e.id = :id",Eleve.class);
    q.setParameter("id",id);
    List<Eleve> listEleve = q.getResultList();
    if(listEleve.size() == 1) {
        return listEleve.get(0);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void cascadeDelGroupeOnEleve(Groupe groupe) {
    TypedQuery<Eleve> q = em.createQuery("Select e FROM Eleve e WHERE e.groupe = ?1",Eleve.class);
    List<Eleve> listEleve = q.setParameter(1,groupe).getResultList();
    for (Eleve eleve: listEleve) {
        eleve.setGroupe(null);
        majEleve(eleve);
    }
}
```

}

The GstionEntityBeans:

```
public static GestionEntitiesBean getGestionEntitiesBean () {

    GestionEntitiesBean gestionEntitiesBean = null;

    try{
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        gestionEntitiesBean = (GestionEntitiesBean) ctx.lookup("java:app/projetasl-ejb/GestionEntitiesEJB");
    } catch( NamingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return gestionEntitiesBean;
}
```

And finally the Error console:

```
@BeforeClass - oneTimeSetUp
@Before - setUp
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.asl.groupb.utils.Utils.getGestionEntitiesBean(Utils.java:24)
    at org.asl.groupb.repositoriesTest.EleveRepositoryTest.setUp(EleveRepositoryTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
@After - tearDown
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.asl.groupb.utils.Utils.getGestionEntitiesBean(Utils.java:24)
    at org.asl.groupb.repositoriesTest.EleveRepositoryTest.setUp(EleveRepositoryTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
@Before - setUp
@After - tearDown
@Before - setUp
@After - tearDown
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.asl.groupb.utils.Utils.getGestionEntitiesBean(Utils.java:24)
    at org.asl.groupb.repositoriesTest.EleveRepositoryTest.setUp(EleveRepositoryTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.asl.groupb.utils.Utils.getGestionEntitiesBean(Utils.java:24)
    at org.asl.groupb.repositoriesTest.EleveRepositoryTest.setUp(EleveRepositoryTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
@Before - setUp
@After - tearDown
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.asl.groupb.utils.Utils.getGestionEntitiesBean(Utils.java:24)
    at org.asl.groupb.repositoriesTest.EleveRepositoryTest.setUp(EleveRepositoryTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
@Before - setUp
@After - tearDown
@AfterClass - oneTimeTearDown
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525385/noinitialcontextexception-error

Comment: @VladimirTikhomirov I don't think this is a dup.  The root problem is running tests in an EE container, and the problem is much more broad than the `NoInitialContextException`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that JUnit drives tests from a Java SE layer, so the threads executing your tests will not execute within a Java EE container.  As you have found, many Java EE operations which require a Java EE container will not be available, such as `InitialContext.lookup()`.

Here is a fairly standard approach that I use to execute JUnit tests in a Java EE Environment:

**Use a JUnit SE suite with basic test stubs to drive GET requests to your application:**

```
@BeforeClass
public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
    // start my app server and make sure apps are installed
}

@AfterClass
public static void oneTimeTearDown() {
    // shut down app server
}

@Test
public void testApplicationAvailable() {
    runTestInServlet("testApplicationAvailable");
}

@Test
public void testThatFails() {
    runTestInServlet("testThatFails");
}

private void runTestInServlet(String testName) {
    // Construct the URL, note that the name of the test is passed in
    // as the value of the "test" parameter.  This will get read from
    // the servlet's doGet method
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9080/myAppName/testServletName?test=" + test);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try{
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        // use the BufferedReader to validate response from test servlet
        // i.e. search for some "successful test" token
    } finally {
        con.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**Use corresponding methods in a test servlet to execute the real test in a Java EE environment:**

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = { "/testServletName" })
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {
        String test = request.getParameter("test");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            System.out.println("-----> " + test + " starting");
            // Use reflection to branch out and invoke the method found in the GET method's "test" parameter
            getClass().getMethod(test, PrintWriter.class).invoke(this, response.getWriter());
            System.out.println("<----- " + test + " successful");
        } catch (Throwable x) {
            System.out.println("<----- " + test + " failed:");
        } finally {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }

    public void testApplicationAvailable(PrintWriter pw) throws Exception {
        System.out.prinln("Application and test servlet available");
    }

    public void testThatFails(PrintWriter pw) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("This test will fail");
    }
}
```

There are third party libs you can use to make this a little more simple, but this is the basic idea.  The examples I showed here can all be done with standard Java libraries (and a Java EE environment, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/ for unit testing, it is much simpler.

Please use following stackoverflow post to see the basic usage and solution to using EntityManager without a container.

[EntityManager is null when unit testing with org.jglue.cdi-unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247268/entitymanager-is-null-when-unit-testing-with-org-jglue-cdi-unit)